# Transportation from Moutiers Salins Station to Courchevel 1650

Tags: public-transport, france

I am going on a ski trip in France, at Courchevel 1650. We are taking the TGV to the "Moutiers Salins Brides Les Bains" station.

How will I get from the train station to my hotel (which is right at the base of the Courchevel 1650 piste/slope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no train lines to all stations. As pnuts comments, Belle Savoie Express has a bus line from Moutiers (train & bus station) to Courchevel 1650.

---

### Timetables

Here you can find the timetable (pdf file): http://www.mairie-courchevel.com/download/PRATIQUE/Transport/2014-2015/lr_t5_la_tania_-_courchevel.pdf

Can also be found here (more dynamic where you can select travel date, and a map of the stops!): http://itineraire.mobisavoie.fr/en/line-timetables/6/LineTimeTable/courchevel-moutiers/369/courchevelgareroutiere-saintbontarentaise/1?KeywordsLine=Courchevel%20-%20Mo%C3%BBtiers&OperatorId=9

The stop may be `COURCHEVEL-MORIOND-OFFICE-DU-TOURISME` for you in this website.

---

### Buying tickets

You can get your tickets here: http://www.mobisavoie.com/7492-achat-d-un-billet-de-car.htm

- Departure: `MOUTIERS`
- Arrival: `COURCHEVEL Moriond 1650`
- Single or return trip
- Add your travel dates

Tickets prices:

- Adult, Single/Return: 12€ / 20,40€
- Child, Single/Return: 9€ / 18€
- Booking fee: 2€
- At night (after 10PM): price doubled

You can then select if your want tickets sent by mail, or etickets that cannot be modified or canceled.

For your information, here is the map of Courchevel 1550 - 1650: 
[Courchevel map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPLPB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There are also a number of taxi companies that will take you from the train station at Moutiers to the various Courchevel resorts:
http://www.courchevel.com/winter/en/taxis-rs93.html

Prices start around 65€ one way for 1-4 people.